# JavaScript functions: structured parameters as object?

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I have a JavaScript function like this whose signature I don't want to change:

```js
const myFunction(color, quantity) {
  ...
}
```

I want to use the function's structured parameters as if they're an object, like this:

```js
const defaults = {color: 'blue', size: 'large'};
const myFunction(color, quantity) {
  // I know this won't work, because the JS arguments object is Array-like, 
  // and doesn't have named keys
  return { ...defaults, ...arguments };
}
console.log(myFunction(red, 22));
/* Should output:
  { color: 'red', size: 'large', quantity: 22 }
*/
```

Is there any way to access parameters like this?

Comment: Well no, because as you've observed parameters are *not* like an object.

Comment: Why not just use `...{ color, size }`?

Comment: Why use `(color, quantity)`? Internally you're using `arguments`

Comment: return { ...defaults, color, quantity };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly spell out the parameter names to create an object from them - you can use the shorthand property syntax though:

```
{ color, size }
```

```js
const defaults = {color: 'blue', size: 'large'};
function myFunction(color, quantity) {
  return { ...defaults, color, quantity };
}
console.log(myFunction('red', 22));
```